# the min function for integers in Z3

Tags: z3

Does Z3 support min function for integer, i.e. return the minimum of two numbers? I failed to find it on Z3's web site.

Furthermore, does it support some kind of function which could return the minimum of a set of numbers? Something like this:
(assert (= y (min x1 x2 x3 x4 x5))),
where x and y are integers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`min` is a reserved keyword for the forthcoming floating point theory.
You can use the `define-fun` command to define the macros `min2` (binary), `min3` (ternary), etc.
Here is an example defining `min2`, `min3` and `min4`.

http://rise4fun.com/Z3/akWje

The SMT 2.0 standard does not support macros with arbitrary number of arguments.
If you prefer, you can use one of the Z3 APIs for doing that. The Python front-end is very flexible. Here is an example in Z3Py.

http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/Vvp

Comment: Thank you very much, Leonardo.
I noticed that min function for a pair or a set of numbers is not included in the standard language of SMT. I just curious about the reason as it is quite common in applications. As we can see, min is an anti-monotone function, i.e. min(S) > min(T) whenever S \subseteq T for sets of numbers S, T, and is implemented in most CSP solvers. Is there any technical reason, for example efficiency issue or increasing the complexity level?

Comment: No, there is no particular reason for not having it in SMT by default. The SMT-Lib standard tries to be minimalist. Since `min` can be defined based on the supported operators, it is not in the standard.

Comment: The rise4fun links are dead; maybe someone can edit the post with the solution :)